# Unable to run flask wsgi app with nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have tried this [blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) to deploy flask app using wsgi server on production

I have followed all the steps which are mentioned

sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-pip

sudo pip install virtualenv uwsgi

`bash
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install flask
pip install -r requirements.txt`

```
touch /home/lucy/myproject.sock
```

created wsgi.py

```
from myproject import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

created a systemd Unit File.

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/myproject.service




[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=lucy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/lucy/
Environment="PATH=/home/lucy/env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/lucy/env/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

We can now start the uWSGI service we created and enable it so that it starts at boot:

`bash
sudo systemctl start myproject
sudo systemctl enable myproject`

### Connecting uWSGI to Nginx

First, install Nginx (if you haven't already).

`bash
sudo apt-get install nginx`

sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/lucy/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

`bash
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo systemctl restart nginx`

still, project is not run nginx gives connection refuse error
but when I tried

```
uwsgi -s /home/lucy/myproject.sock -w wsgi:app -H /home/lucy/env --http-processes=10 --chmod-socket=666 --master
```

project is running sucessfully.

Can anyone please tell what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject` should be a `*.conf` conf  ending configure file.

Comment: I have already added seamlink in site-enabled sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject /etc/nginx/sites-enabled and have entry in nginx.conf

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `uwsgi` is not installed in the virtual environment, yet in your service file you are asking it to load from the virtual environment path:

```
ExecStart=/home/lucy/env/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini
```

You should either install `uwsgi` in your virtual environment, or give the path to the global `uwsgi` in your service description; you can get that by typing `which uwsgi` in your shell.

It is recommended to install `uwsgi` in your virtual environment as it will contain the latest updates and features.

To do this run:

```
env/bin/pip install uwsgi
```

Make sure in all cases to restart the service (if you change the service definition file, you'll have to reload the service as well).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I installed the uwsgi in python environment it gives Requirement already satisfied: uwsgi in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: That is not the Python environment, that is the global Python environment.